# how to update the sql database after the drag and drop between two list in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

can someone please help me? I already connected the parameter value of the 2 tables in database to the list so my only problem is to save their position on sql database after I drag and drop.

Here is my MasterControl-AccessType.aspx:

```js
 var adjustment;
       
        $("ol.simple_with_animation").sortable({
              group: 'simple_with_animation',
              pullPlaceholder: false,
              // animation on drop
              onDrop: function  ($item, container, _super) {

                var $clonedItem = $('<li/>').css({height: 0});
                $item.before($clonedItem);
                $clonedItem.animate({ 'height': $item.height() });
       
                $item.animate($clonedItem.position(), function  () {
                  $clonedItem.detach();
                  _super($item, container);


                });
              },

              // set $item relative to cursor position
              onDragStart: function ($item, container, _super) {
                var offset = $item.offset(),
                    pointer = container.rootGroup.pointer;

                adjustment = {
                  left: pointer.left - offset.left,
                  top: pointer.top - offset.top
                };

                _super($item, container);
              },
              onDrag: function ($item, position) {
                $item.css({
                  left: position.left - adjustment.left,
                  top: position.top - adjustment.top
                });
              }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <head>
    
        <!--ONLINE Resource----------------------------------------START-->
        
        <!-- Boostrap  START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Boostrap END-->
                
        <!--Font Awesome START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!--Font Awesome END-->
        
        <!--CUSTOM CSS for Profile iFrames START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Profile-Grid.css">
        <!--CUSTOM CSS for Profile iFrames END-->

        <!--JQuery START-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--JQuery END-->
        
        <!--JQuery UI START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--JQuery UI END-->
        
        <!--ONLINE Resource------------------------------------------END-->
        
        <!---------------------------------DIVISION-------------------------------------------------->
        
        <!--OFFLINE Resource---------------------------------------START-->
        
        <!-- Boostrap  START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <!-- Boostrap END-->
        
        <!--Font Awesome START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!--Font Awesome END-->
    
        <!--CUSTOM CSS for Profile iFrames START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Profile-Grid.css">              
        <!--CUSTOM CSS for Profile iFrames END-->
        
        <!--JQquery START-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--JQuery END-->
        
        <!--JQuery UI START-->        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.css">
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css">
        
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>        
        <!--JQuery UI END-->
        
        <!--OFFLINE Resource-----------------------------------------END-->
        
        <link href="css/vendor.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src='js/application.js'></script>

    </head>
      
        <div id ="list">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        
            <div class="content_title">Select Functions</div>
            
            <div class="content_body">
                
                <ol class=".Drag-N-Drop simple_with_animation vertical">
                    <%
                        
                        int js = sideMenuNows.Length;
                        for(int i = 0; i < js; i++) { 
                        Response.Write("<li id='Drag-N-Drop-list'>"+sideMenuNows[i]+"</li>");
                    }
                %>
                </ol>
                
            </div><!--content_body END-->
            
            
            <div class="content_footer">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-pull-right"></i>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        
            <div class="content_title">All Functions</div>
            
            <div class="content_body">
                
                <ol class=".Drag-N-Drop simple_with_animation vertical">
                    <%
                     
                     int j = sideMenuUpdates.Length;
                     for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                     {

                         Response.Write("<li id='Drag-N-Drop-list'>"+sideMenuUpdates[i]+"</li>");
                     }
                %> 
                </ol>
                
                
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="content_footer">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left pull-left"></i>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
    </div> <!--row MAIN END-->
    
</div> <!--container fluid END-->
 </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by sending the positions using Ajax call to a ASP.NET generic handler that will save them to the database. You can use Ajax inside `onDrag` function like this:

```
onDrag: function ($item, position) {
                    $item.css({
                      left: position.left - adjustment.left,
                      top: position.top - adjustment.top
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "SavePositionHandler.ashx",
                      data: { LeftPos: position.left, TopPos: position.top },
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (response) {
                             alert(response.d);
                     }
                }); 
}
```

`SavePositionHandler.ashx` code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class SavePositionHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string LeftPos = context.Request.Form["LeftPos"];
        string TopPos = context.Request.Form["TopPos"];

        //now you have the data on the server side. Save it to database.
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
       get
       {
            return false;
       }
    }
}
```

This code is not tested and just for example purpose.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but it still no working. any idea of what to do? Thank you.

Comment: Can someone please give me a webmethod for this? Thank you.

Comment: @vtomas share the code you are trying. My code is just an example not the final solution. You need to modify according to your needs.

Comment: i don't have any code as of now cause i'm really clueless about using array in drag and drop. Do you by chance know how to use webmethod instead of http handler on my case?